# What's the suitable optimization model for solving the given model?

Tags: optimization

Given the following model, what's the suitable optimization model for it?
[image]

- $X_{i,j}^N$ is a Matrix. (is known, and $N$ stands for Normalized. It means, $X_{i,j}^N$ is normalized version of $X_{i,j}$; so, $N$ is not an operator.)
- $w$ is a vector (we are looking for $w$ in this case) (unknown)
- $\sigma^N$ is a vector (is known, and $N$ stands for normalized)
- $\pi_j^N$ is a vector (is known, and $N$ stands for normalized)
- $\epsilon=10^{-3}$
- $\beta$ is a floating point scaler (is known)

Comment: Is $\beta$ known?  What does the $N$ superscript mean?  Why have both $\lambda_b$ and $\lambda_c$ when (8.4) and (8,5) force them to be equal?

Comment: @RobPratt, $N$ stands for Normalized. It's just like a name. It's not an operator. Yes, $\beta$ is a floating point scaler like 0.8 or anything else. *"Why have both $\lambda_b$ and $\lambda_c$ when (8.4) and (8,5) force them to be equal?"* I don't know, unfortunately.

Comment: @RobPratt, I edited it. They miswrote equation (8.5) in their paper. I found the correct replacement and updated it.

Comment: What is the paper? If you eliminate $\lambda_b$ and $\lambda_c$ by substitution, you then have a quadratic programming (QP) problem, which you can solve with a QP solver.

Comment: @RobPratt, This is the [doi to the paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.15388/Informatica.2018.167). You will find their mistake if you check page 271 (7 in the pdf). Thank you!

Comment: The $S_i$ are known or unknown quantities? If unknown, why not just combine (8.2) and (8.3) and eliminate $S_i$?

Comment: Is $\beta > 0$?

Comment: @prubin, Yes, $\beta \ge0$. $S_i$ is unknown and depends on the values of $w_i$. *"why not just combine (8.2) and (8.3) and eliminate $S_i$?"* Then how will that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can eliminate a few variables and rewrite the problem as follows:
\begin{align*}
\max\lambda_{a}-\beta\left[\sum_{j}\left(w_{j}-\sigma_{j}^{N}\right)^{2}+\sum_{j}\left(w_{j}-\pi_{j}^{N}\right)^{2}\right]\\
\textrm{s.t. }\sum_{j}w_{j}x_{ij}^{N} - \lambda_{a}& \ge 0\\
\sum_{j}w_{j} & =1\\
w_{j} & \le1\quad\forall j\\
w_{j} & \ge\epsilon\quad\forall j
\end{align*}
noting that the constraint $w_j \le 1$ is actually redundant give the constraints above and below it. Since the quantity inside the square brackets is convex in $w,$ the objective is concave and quadratic, and the constraints are linear. So you have an ordinary quadratic programming problem, which can be solved by quite a few solvers, both commercial (CPLEX, Gurobi, Xpress) and open-source.

Comment: Thank you, professor! I got your point. Thanks for the hints and clarification.